# How to connect to webcam in Java?

Tags: java, webcam, hardware-interface

I have a form in which i want to capture the image of the person and display that image in the form.

How can i connect to the webcam through java and display that image in the form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004405/how-to-capture-video-from-webcamin-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) to capture the image.

This code should get you started (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java)):

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
public class GrabberShow implements Runnable {
    //final int INTERVAL=1000;///you may use interval
    IplImage image;
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
    public GrabberShow() {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); 
        int i=0;
        try {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img;
            while (true) {
                img = grabber.grab();
                if (img != null) {
                    cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                    cvSaveImage((i++)+"-capture.jpg", img);
                    // show image on window
                    canvas.showImage(img);
                }
                 //Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to use the Java Media Framework ([JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)). You can find an example [here](http://leejava.wordpress.com/2009/09/23/jmf-webcam-app-with-saving-jpeg/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Webcam Capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) project to do that. It's working on Windows XP, Vista, 7, Linux, Mac OS, Raspberry Pi and more. There is a ready-to-use Swing component extending JPanel which can be used to display image from your webcam. Please found [this example](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java/WebcamViewerExample.java) for more details of how this can be done - it presents some advanced capabilities of this component, but basic usage would be the following:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("Test webcam panel");
window.add(new WebcamPanel(Webcam.getDefault()));
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

After you run this code you should see JFrame with image from your webcam inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
Webcam.setAutoOpenMode(true);
BufferedImage image = Webcam.getDefault().getImage();
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("F:/test.png"));
```

can download the latest version from https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

and add other library file that in the zip file