# Java WebCam Capture And Display

Tags: java, image, swing, webcam, image-capture

Im currently looking to building a simple application.

I've had a look at other application and stack overflow questions which dont seem to help.

I want to make the application use the build i web camera to take a image and show in in a swing gui.. Then take a another picture say 2 seconds later.. Check if its the same as the first and discard it if its else show it?

I have the following questions:

- What libairys to i need to use to grab pictures from my webcam?
- How do i dertimine when the picture has changed i.e. take a picture compare it to last save  if its any differnt?

Is there away to do this easily and not use lots and lots of libarys?

Is there any example/simple code out there?

Answer (score 5):

To grab the picture take a look at [How to capture video from webcam(in java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004405/how-to-capture-video-from-webcamin-java)

Have a lot of examples about hoe to find differences between two images, google it:

[Java Image Comparison / Motion Detection](http://mindmeat.blogspot.com.br/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html)

You can use Java Media Framework, OpenCv...

I think that this gitHub project can help you a lot [sarxos/webcam-capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture)

Comment: Cant seemt o get it working using sarxos/webcam-capture

Comment: The sarxos/webcam-capture does have motion detector feature which will tell you that there was a change in the scene. Please check this link for details (there are 3 examples for motion detection) and/or create the ticket in project on Github if you have problems with that: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java

Answer (score 1):

you can use [lti-civil](http://lti-civil.org/) library,completely written in java for capturing images from webcam.For comparing two images you should write some image matching algorithms.
Another alternative is [javacv](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) (java wrapper for openCV) which can be usefull for grabbing images from webcam as well as compairing two images.